# how to link to a specific tab in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a menu screen - a UIViewController, which has some buttons that navigate a UITabBar..  Currently, when I load the UITabBar, it always goes to the first tab, however, i would like each button on the UIViewController to load a respective tab in the UITabBar but cannot seem to figure it out..

I've searched near and far to no avail - any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use setSelectedIndex property of UITabBar,

And spend some time with documentation - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

it will help you.

Comment: right,thanks - i've tried that but cannot figure out where to use it..  I know, prb sounding stupid right about now - maybe i'm doing it wrong - i currently have a UIViewController adding the UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>, do i need to replace that and load the UITabBar directly?

Comment: Its totally depends upon your requirement..In the case of ViewController as a rootViewController you should use this property at each button press event.